# Translating Terminal Command to Subprocess Library

Tags: python, subprocess, apple-configurator

I'm trying to pull data from iOS devices that are attached to my Mac.

I have enabled the automation tool option in Configurator and am able to use cfgutil from terminal.

When I run the command `cfgutil --format JSON -f get ECID` in Terminal a JSON is returned with a `"Devices"` key that has a list of ECID's in the value.

When I try to run that command through a python script I keep getting errors.

```
getDevices = subprocess.check_output(["cfgutil", "--format JSON", "-f", "get", "ECID"])
```

returns "cfgutil: error: Unknown option '--format JSON'

Any idea what is preventing Terminal from just running the command and getting the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every argument needs to be a separate list element, you can't put `--format` and `JSON` in the same string.

```
getDevices = subprocess.check_output(["cfgutil", "--format", "JSON", "-f", "get", "ECID"])
```

Comment: Thank you. That addressed the issue.